# Getting all children of Flowlayoutpanel in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have a `Flowlayoutpanel` with an unknown amount of children. How can I retrieve all the children? So far I have tried this with no success:

```
private LoopReturn(Control control)
{    
    var c = control;

    var list = new List<Control>();

    while (c != null)
    {
        list.Add(c);
        c = c.GetNextControl(c, true);                    
    }

    foreach (var control1 in list)
        Debug.Print(control.Name);  
}
```

But I'm only getting the first two children. Does anybody know why?

**EDIT:**

I need to the children of all children of all children etc.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var controls = flowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<Control>();
```

Bear in mind that this is linear, not hierarchical, **just like your current algorithm.**

---

To get the all children, regardless of level, you'd need to do something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Control> GetChildren(Control control = null)
{
    if (control == null) control = flowLayoutPanel;

    var list = control.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList();

    foreach (var child in list)
        list.AddRange(GetChildren(child));

    return list;
}
```

and then when you want the overall list just do this:

```
var controls = GetChildren();
```

Comment: I'm only getting the first child using this, not the children of children etc.

Comment: @Dimo, then this will do that for you.

Comment: I want to get the children of the children, your code does not do that. It only gets the first child. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Dimo, no. I stated that clearly. But your code as shown doesn't get the children of the children either. If that's what you're looking for then make sure you state that clearly in your question. Let me edit.

Comment: I get "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function would work:

```
private IEnumerable<Control> ChildControls(Control parent) {
  List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
  controls.Add(parent);
  foreach (Control ctrl in parent.Controls) {
    controls.AddRange(ChildControls(ctrl));
  }
  return controls;
}
```

Then to call it:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in ChildControls(flowLayoutPanel1)) {
  Debug.Print(ctrl.Name);
}
```