# Get children UserControls of flowlyaoutpanel in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `FlowlyoutPanel` that contains number of `Usercontrols` added on runtime. I want to loop through all and get each of them so that I can play with their properties.  But following way is not working, and I am unable to get each control inside `flowlayoutpanel`

```
using (CareplusEntities context = new CareplusEntities())
 {
   foreach(Control ct  in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
    {
      ct.anyUserControlProperty;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? You've forgot to add a question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all children of Flowlayoutpanel in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232057/getting-all-children-of-flowlayoutpanel-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Cid updated ! actually it's not working i am unable to get controls. !

Comment: That `new CareplusEntities` looks awfully fishy.  A standard bug is to create a new form object instead of using the instance that you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`OfType<TResult>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_OfType__1_System_Collections_IEnumerable_) extension method:

```
foreach(var ct in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<UserControlTypeHere>())
(
    ct.UserControlProperty = value;
)
```

Of course, you need to change `UserControlTypeHere` to the type of the actual user control.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one type only you like to search for you could use the `OfType<>()` LINQ mehtod:

```
foreach(var control in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<MyUserControl>())
{
    control.mySpecialProperty = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

If you have several types of controls, than you need some kind of dispatcher. Most easiest would be some kind of `Dictionary<Type, Action<Control>>`.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<Control>> _Dispatcher = new Dictionary<Type, Action<Control>>
{
    { typeof(MyControl), HandleMyFirstControl },
    { typeof(AnotherControl), HandleMySecondControl },
};

private static void HandleMyFirstControl(Control control)
{
    var myControl = (MyControl)control;
    myControl.MySpecialValue = 73;
}

private static void HandleMySecondControl(Control control)
{
    var anotherControl = (AnotherControl)control;
    anotherControl.Foo = Guid.NewGuid();
}

private void HandleControls()
{
    foreach(var control in flowLayoutPanel.Controls)
    {
        if(_Dispatcher.TryGetValue(control.GetType(), out Action<Control> handler)
        {
            handler(control);
        }
    }
}
```